# How to change a default value and use the new one?

Tags: javascript

I have an input text field with default value:

```
<input type="text" id="lvKey" name="lvKey" value="vb4Kiu">
```

And I have a button:

```
<input type="button" id="startButton" value="Start">
```

The user shall be able to write another code into the textfield and start a function based on his own value (e.q. new value 's621pV') by click on the button. Therefore i tried:

```
var startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
var lvKey = document.getElementById('lvKey').value;

startButton.onclick = function(){
  level(lvKey);
}
```

I don't understand how to change the default value. Google wasn't helpful...

```js
var startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
var lvKey = document.getElementById('lvKey').value;

startButton.onclick = function() {
  level(lvKey);
}

function level(lvKey) {
  console.log(lvKey);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="lvKey" name="lvKey" value="vb4Kiu">
<input type="button" id="startButton" value="Start">
```

Comment: what is level function doing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to *get* the input value *after* the button is clicked, so you have to move `var lvKey = document.getElementById('lvKey').value;` inside `startButton.onclick = function(){`:

```
var startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');

startButton.onclick = function(){
  var lvKey = document.getElementById('lvKey').value;
  level(lvKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you move the value into the onclick function - you can then get it and pass that to another function which can then do something with the value it has been given.

```js
var startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');

startButton.onclick = function(){
  var lvKey = document.getElementById('lvKey').value;
  level(lvKey);
}

function level(val) {
  console.log(val);  // consoles the value of the input
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="lvKey" name="lvKey" value="vb4Kiu">
<input type="button" id="startButton" value="Start">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get value of input in `onclick` function

```js
document.getElementById('startButton').onclick = function(){
  var lvKey = document.getElementById('lvKey').value;
  console.log(lvKey);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="lvKey" name="lvKey" value="vb4Kiu">
<input type="button" id="startButton" value="Start">
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the value of the input AFTER the click.

```js
var startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');


startButton.onclick = function(){
  var lvKey = document.getElementById('lvKey').value;
  level(lvKey);
}

function level(lvKey){
console.log(lvKey)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="lvKey" name="lvKey" value="vb4Kiu">


<input type="button" id="startButton" value="Start">
```